# Problem with an update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want the statement update the database by 1 each time I enter a specific page..But it seems to update it by 3 :(

```
   public static void UpdateThreadView(int threadID)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("UPDATE  dbo.Threads");
    sb.Append(" SET Views=(Views+1)");
    sb.Append(" WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadID");

    string myConnectionString = AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), myConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ThreadID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ThreadID"].Value = threadID;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP .NET Web Forms? In which part of the page life-cycle are you calling this method?

Comment: This SQL code is essentially irrelevant (it looks fine). Please edit your question with the ASP.NET code that calls this method; that's most likely where the problem is.

Comment: might be where condition meets with 3 rows so update 3 rows

Comment: It is in the page load.. you eneter the page and it is in the page..load..it delivers it the page id..  oooh.. so how can i change the query.. The treadID is the number of the thread... can be 50 too.. why wont it add 1 to the view?

Comment: Your code seem's ok. Check how many times and where you are calling UpdateThreadView

Comment: The only way this updates by 3 is if it gets called 3 times.

Comment: okay. So my sql code id okay,, i have to worry about is the number of times it is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in your code and run in the visual studio debugger.

I'm betting this gets called 3 times due to a combination of postback and events.

Alternatively you could use SQL Profiler to see if multiple updates happen.

Comment: Sorry i was stupid, and you were right.. i put the calling method inside !ispostback..thank you all

Answer (score 1):

sparks advice is really good. Learn to know the debugger. There are some real sweet things you can do with breakpoints and the Immediate window that will help you become a much more efficient.

On a site note. How you use the Stringbuilder is not very efficient. Generally speaking unless you are doing things in a loop avoid the stringbuilder as there are some overhead to the creation of it.

```
var str = "UPDATE  dbo.Threads" 
          + " SET Views=(Views+1)"
          + " WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadID";
```

This type of code will be optimized by the compiler to be one string assignment anyway. I created a small test which showed that on 1000000 iterations the stringbuilder takes 467 ms while string concatenation takes 8. It won't kill your application but might be good to know.